# Customize alarm message from AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I got some alarm notifications from AWS Cloudwatch to my email but they are usually sent in a JSON format and the problem is that some of those emails are getting received by non-technical people in my company. I was wondering if that is possible to customize the emails sent by AWS SNS because I don't see any option in how to customize it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are using Cloudwatch/Event/Rules then you can use "Input transfomer" to customize the contents of the email and then SNS will send that instead of JSON.

I am using this setup to get notified when user signs in AWS console.
In my case "Event Source" is "AWS Console Sign-in" but you can try with Cloudwatch and see if that gets you what you need.

See the screenshot, hope it helps.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-Input-Transformer-Tutorial.html

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=820808

[image]

Comment: This is what a developer needs! The guidance. Good answer. Why people don't upvote or accept this?

Comment: By the way where I can find the all possible JSON parameters to be set? Like {"state" : "$.detail.state", "instance" : "$.detail.instance-id"}

Comment: In case someone reading didn't notice: Don't forget the quotes in each key and value, and in the final string

Comment: Alarms and CloudWatch events are two different things right? I don't know if one can use Input Transformer on a simple Alarm notification action. I am very interested into that.

Comment: It seems EventBridge is replacing Cloudwatch events. Fortunately, Input transformers are also supported in EventBridge https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-input-transformer-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

you trigger a lambda function from your SNS topic, take the event and either send it via SNS or SES. SES supports sending HTML mails, SNS just plain text mails.

I normally do the following approach:
Alarm -> SNS -> Lambda -> SES (HTML)

> received by non-technical people in my company

I'd use a basic HTML template with buttons and nice looking text :-)

I created a post and a GitHub repository for that:

https://medium.com/@sandro_volpicella/how-to-customise-cloudwatch-alarm-notifications-with-lambda-ses-html-and-cdk-f0094b07fed6

https://github.com/AlessandroVol23/cloudwatch-custom-email-cdk

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the notifications from SNS sent via e-mail.

If you really need to customize them, you should look into SNS notifications via SES (Simple Email Service)